# Separate 1 Coordinates column into 2 Lat and Long Columns Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm running a query on a database and I have a "coordinate" column in a table. The data in the coordinates column is in the following format:

```
{"lat":40.74,"lng":-73.98}
```

I need to run a query that will display the latitude and longitude in separate columns, so there would be a column labeled "latitude" that displays 40.74 and another column labeled "longitude" that displays 73.98.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming is json your column data type you can select each element like this :

```
SELECT 
  column ->>'lat'::text AS lat, 
  column ->>'long'::text AS long 
FROM table
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/91927/20)

Also as note that's nothing to be with the question, consider using [PostGIS](http://postgis.org/) to store and manage spatial data.

Answer (score 0):

CREATE TABLE tbPlace
(
PlaceId int,
coord varchar(255)
);

insert into tbPlace(placeId, coord)
values(1, '"lat":40.74,"lng":-73.98');

insert into tbPlace(placeId, coord)
values(1, '"lat":-20.74,"lng":20.98');

select 
placeId
,cast(substr(coord, instr(coord, 'lat')+5, instr(coord, ',')-instr(coord, 'lat')+5) as float) as latitude1
,cast(substr(coord, instr(coord, 'lng')+5, length(coord)-instr(coord, 'lng')+5) as float) as longitude1
from tbPlace;

drop table tbplace;